# SQL: How to update from 'tableA pointing to tableB' to 'tableA poiting to tableC pointing to tableB' without losing existing element relation?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Basically I want an intermediary `Book`, between what was a direct link from `Line` to `User`. `Line` elements already exist and can't lose the relation to corresponding already existing `User` element, so a default `Book` element needs to be created which handles already existing data.

Tables were created like this:

```
User (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

Line (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,    
    title VARCHAR(300),            
    id_user INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES User(id)
);
```

Now I need to create some SQL code that would produce tables like this:

```
User (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

Book (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,    
    title VARCHAR(300),            
    id_user INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES User(id)
);

Line (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,    
    title VARCHAR(300),            
    id_book INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_book) REFERENCES Book(id)
);
```

... except that data already exists. so I have Line elements pointing to User elements and I can't create new tables from scratch. So I need the SQL code to modify the existing structure.

Basically I just want users to have books and books to have lines, instead of users have lines. And already existing lines to get a connection with the owner users. What would be the best approach?

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Some sample data representing what my database looks like currently:

```
Table user(id,username)
- 1, user1
- 2, user2
- 3, user3

Table line(id,title,id_user)
- 1, line1, 1
- 2, line2, 1
- 3, linex, 1
- 4, line1, 2
- 5, liney, 2
```

The output should be the following database:

```
Table user(id,username)
- 1, user1
- 2, user2
- 3, user3

Table book(id,title,id_user)
- 1, 'default', 1
- 2, 'default', 2
- 3, 'default', 3

Table line(id,title,id_book)
- 1, line1, 1
- 2, line2, 1
- 3, linex, 1
- 4, line1, 2
- 5, liney, 2
```

////////////////////////////////

What my pipeline currently looks like, my main problem is producing the final query:

```
    create table book
      $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book(
      id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      title VARCHAR(300),
      id_user INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 

      FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES User(id)
    ); ";

    $conn->exec($sql);


    //insert default book corresponding to every user
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Book(title, id_user) SELECT DISTINCT 'default', id FROM User;";
    $conn->exec($sql);

    //insert id_book foreign key into Line table pointing to Book table
    $sql = "ALTER TABLE Line ADD id_book INT;"

    $conn->exec($sql);

    //make Line.id_book foreign key pointing to Line.id
    $sql="ALTER TABLE Line ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_book) REFERENCES User(id);"

    $conn->exec($sql);

    //unfinished
    $sql = "UPDATE
                Line
            SET
                Line.id_book = Book.id
            WHERE
                Line.id_user = Book.id_user"
```

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks, I've uploaded the question to try to avoid the XY problem. So basically I'm looking for approaches in the form of an SQL statement (or a pipeline of statements).

Comment: Sample data of input and output is important as we want to test the code we produce. You also need to supply what queries you have tried. imo,  This looks like an interesting problem, that can be sorted out, with enough assistance from you. :)

Comment: @RyanVincent ok, I've updated the question once more and included the extra information. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create table `book` (like you already did):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book(
      id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      title VARCHAR(300),
      id_user INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,     
      FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES User(id)
);
```

Populate the new table:

```sql
INSERT INTO Book(title, id_user) SELECT 'default', id FROM User;
```

I removed `DISTINCT` from your code because `id` is primary/unique and thus every selected row is guaranteed to be unique.

Add column `id_book` to the `line` table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Line ADD id_book INT UNSIGNED;
```

It must be `INT UNSIGNED` to match the referenced data type.

Add foreign key:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Line ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_book) REFERENCES book(id);
```

It should reference a book, not a user like in your code.

Update data (Relate the line with the users (first) book):

```sql
UPDATE Line
SET Line.id_book = (
  SELECT book.id
  FROM book
  WHERE book.id_user = Line.id_user
  ORDER BY book.id
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Drop `line.id_user` column:

```sql
-- use "SHOW CREATE TABLE line" to find out the foreign key name
ALTER TABLE Line DROP FOREIGN KEY line_ibfk_1;
ALTER TABLE Line DROP id_user;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3faa13/1

Note: If a user has two or more books, you don't know wich one to link with a `line`. In your question you didn't define how to handle this case. So i decided to take the first book by `id` (`ORDER BY book.id LIMIT 1`).

The UPDATE statement could also be:

```sql
UPDATE Line
SET Line.id_book = (
  SELECT MIN(book.id)
  FROM book
  WHERE book.id_user = Line.id_user
);
```